# Can Windows Server 2008 Standard (not-R2) 64-bit without Hyper-V be upgraded to Windows Server 2012 Standard?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, upgrade

I reviewed the upgrade path [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/installation-and-upgrade).

It mentions that I should be able to upgrade:

[image]

My version matches except for the "Hyper-V" part.

[image]

The error I receive when trying to upgrade is:

> Windows Server® 2008 Standard without Hyper-V cannot be upgraded to
>   Windows Server 2012 Standard

Is there any way to upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Windows Server® 2008 Standard without Hyper-V" is a different edition. It can not be upgraded in place.